# Cycle through imported images in NextJS logo carousel with Vite

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite

I am looking to build an automatic logo carousel of sorts in NextJS. I'm building a next app on vite if that makes a difference.
I have imported the different images and assigned them values as such Logo1, Logo2, etc
I want to have an array of the images that cycle in and out after a set amount of time.

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import Logo1 from '../public/Assets/random1.png'
import Logo2 from '../public/Assets/random2.png'
import Logo3 from '../public/Assets/random3.png'

const LogoCarousel = () => {

  const Images1 = [Logo1, Logo2, Logo3];
  const Slot1 = useRef();

  let index = 0;

  const change = () => {
    Slot1.src = Images1[index];
    index > 1 ? index = 0 : index++;
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    setInterval(change, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div className='logo-carousel'>
      <div className="logo-slot1" useRef={Slot1} >
        <Image src={Slot1} width={50} height={50} />
      </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default LogoCarousel
```

I've looked through next documentation as well as react but am still struggling.
I tried having a seperate images file with all assets imported and tried to pull from their to no luck either. Also tried using 'Images1' as the Image tag src.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit on the Next.js version and where your component is stored in your file-structure.

One solution that should work regardless of the above, might be to not import your Images in the way you are doing but to rely on the fact that files in the `public` directory are exposed and available via URL.

That means you can use the `src` Attribute of `next/Image` like "normal".

```
        <Image src="/Assets/random1.png" width={50} height={50} />
```

Two other things come to mind when looking at your component:

1. It's accessing the `window` object. That might lead to problems if you try to server render your component, which you might wanna do at some point if you are using Next.js
2. The use of `useRef` is not really justified here. If you want to learn how to use it checkout the [react docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

For your use-case consider the following change to your code:

```
const images = ["random1.png", "random2.png", "random3.png"];

const LogoCarousel = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setIndex(index+1) , 3000);
  },[])

  return (
    <div className='logo-carousel'>
      <div className="logo-slot1" useRef={Slot1} >
        <Image src={`/Assets/${images[index]}`} width={50} height={50} />
      </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

You might not want to just copy paste this, as I wrote this without trying it. But notice how it's possible to live without the use of `window` and `useRef` by using [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) and [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)